# Returning from caught "RuntimeError" always gives `None` python

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

So I have a class with two methods in it:

```
class Test:
    def cycle(self, n=float("inf"), block="x"):
        try:            
            self.cycle(n-1, block)
        except RuntimeError as e:
            if str(e) == "maximum recursion depth exceeded":
                print("... forever")
                return 10
    def f(self):
        try: 
            raise Exception()
        except:
            return 10
        return 20


x = Test()
print(x.cycle())
print(x.f())
```

and it outputs:

```
... forever
None
10
```

What gives? Why can I return from one except and not the other? I can print normally from the first except as well, but it always returns `None`

Comment: Hum, I just try put the `return 10` out of the `except RuntimeError as e:`. And it's working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the method `cycle()` is recursive, but when you call it recursively you are not returning the result returned by the recursive call.

So inside `self.cycle()` , lets say you call `self.cycle()` again, and then in that when trying to call `self.cycle()` the RuntimeError occurs, so that call returns `10` back to the first `self.cycle()` call, but this (lets say first `self.cycle()` ) call does not return this result back to its caller, so the result returned by the second `self.cycle()` is lost, and you get returned `None`.

If you return the result of `self.cycle()` call, you should get correct result. Example -

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(3)
>>> class Test:
...     def cycle(self, n=float("inf"), block="x"):
...         try:
...             return self.cycle(n-1, block)
...         except RuntimeError as e:
...             if str(e) == "maximum recursion depth exceeded":
...                 print("... forever")
...                 return 10
...
>>> t = Test()
>>> print(t.cycle())
... forever
10
```

Please note, I set the recursion limit to 3 so that the recursion depth exceeded error occurs after 3 levels of recursion.

Comment: Ah, how silly of me. Here was I thinking python had a special complicated way of handling `RuntimeError`'s when it was simply a missed `return` statement. Thank you